# Every finite extension of a finite field is Galois

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

> Let $F$ be a finite field. Let $E/F$ be a field extension of degree $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that $E/F$ is Galois.

I would like to varify my answer because I am absolutely sure about it;

$F$ is finite so $p=\text{char}(F)>0$. Thus $\mathbb{F}_p\subseteq F$, and this extension is finite because $F$ is finite. Suppose $n=[F:\mathbb{F}_p]$. Hence $F\cong\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$.

$$[E:\mathbb{F}_p]=[E:F]\cdot[F:\mathbb{F}_p]=m\cdot n$$
Thus, $E\cong\mathbb{F}_{p^{mn}}$ and $E$ is the splitting field of $x^{p^{nm}}-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. So $E/\mathbb{F}_p$ is Galois.

Hence, $E/F$ is Galois.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it looks correct.

Comment: Well, just a short note: you didn't mention that $x^{p^{nm}}-x$ is separable. I hope you remember that it's important here.

Comment: @Mark Not any more important than it would be over $\Bbb Q$. Finite fields are also perfect.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I know. You need to write one of the following: the polynomial is separable or that you know that finite fields are perfect.

Comment: @Arthur Though at this point, when working through such an exercise, this may not be known yet. So it seems worth while making explicit.

Comment: Indeed, writing down the polynomial you did is probably the best possible way of showing that every algebraic extension of a finite field is separable.